# How do I hide my class element when data-reviews is less than 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried using basic JavaScript when `data-reviews="2"` and it worked, but what I need is when `data-reviews` is less than 5 or any specific number, the whole `<span>` section should be hidden. I need assistance on this. I am trying to achieve the same outcome but I want to hide this, when data reviews has < 5.

```html
<div class="collection-list-badge">
  <span class="stamped-product-reviews-badge" data-id="5649263493270" style="display:block;"> 
    <span class="stamped-badge" data-rating="5.0" data-lang="en" aria-label="Rated 5.0 out 42reviews"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="stamped-badge-caption" data-reviews="42" data-rating="5.0" data-label="reviews" aria-label="42 reviews" data-version="2">42</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There are two span element with a `data-rating` attributes, and three spans in total. So, what do you specifically mean when you're saying "span section"?

Comment: There currently is no CSS selector for numerical attribute selection (attributes probably aren’t supposed to be this dynamic). But this is possible in JS: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-reviews]")).filter(({ dataset: { reviews } }) => reviews < 5)` is a list of all `<span data-reviews>` elements where that attribute has a value less than 5. Not sure what “the whole `<span>` section” is, but if you then want to hide the ascendant `<div class="collection-list-badge">`, append a `.forEach((span) => span.closest(".collection-list-badge").hidden = true)`. But this needs more details…

Comment: thanks @SebastianSimon i want to hide this class "collection-list-badge" if reviews is less than 5

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a free coding service. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the badge elements. For each collection badge select the  review element. Parse the `data-reviews` attribute with `parseInt`. Check if the review is less than `5`. If so, remove the collection badge element.

```js
const collectionListBadges = document.querySelectorAll('.collection-list-badge');

for (const collectionListBadge of collectionListBadges) {
  const reviewsElement = collectionListBadge.querySelector('[data-reviews]');
  const amountOfReviews = parseInt(reviewsElement.getAttribute('data-reviews'));
  
  if (amountOfReviews < 5) {
    collectionListBadge.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="collection-list-badge">
  <span class="stamped-product-reviews-badge" data-id="5649263493270" style="display:block;"> 
    <span class="stamped-badge" data-rating="5.0" data-lang="en" aria-label="Rated 5.0 out 42reviews"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="stamped-badge-caption" data-reviews="42" data-rating="5.0" data-label="reviews" aria-label="42 reviews" data-version="2">42</span>
</div>

<div class="collection-list-badge">
  <span class="stamped-product-reviews-badge" data-id="5649263493270" style="display:block;"> 
    <span class="stamped-badge" data-rating="4.0" data-lang="en" aria-label="Rated 4.0 out 38reviews"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="stamped-badge-caption" data-reviews="4" data-rating="4.0" data-label="reviews" aria-label="38 reviews" data-version="2">4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution worked as well . Only had to change data-rating to data-reviews since i want the condition to run on reviews. Thanks man

Comment: Ah, I misread. Let me fix that.